# Unix-bash cd command and then tab shows both directories and files

Tags: bash, unix, tab-completion, rhel6, bash-completion

In unix bash shell, when I type in `cd` and then press tab, it lists both directories and files as the available options to choose. Displaying directories and probably links to the directories must be intuitive. Wouldn't listing the files counter intuitive?

For example, ./ and then tab lists only the items that have execute permissions, which is smart.

Why doesn't bash have the same smarts with cd command? Is it a bug?

Comment: I just tried and didn't notice the behaviour you are describing; are you sure of it?

Comment: Apparently, yes. I'm using Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64. It was same even in Linux 5.9. 
Bash version:
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Thomas, Do you mean, cd+tab complete only directories for you? Which Linux are you using?

Comment: Yes, it only completes directories; I tried with Linux Mint 17 and Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: It seems like every distro I've used has had a different set of completion rules enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following command to your `bashrc`:

```
complete -d cd  # or ``complete -A directory cd''
```

then it'll only auto-complete dirs (including symlinks to dirs) for the `cd` command.

See *[Programmable Completion Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins)* in bash's manual for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you are getting filename completion. `bash` has just enough built-in smarts to recognize that a command name must have executable permission, so it limits `./` + Tab to executable files. Completing *arguments* to `cd` falls under the domain of *programmable* completion (because it is possible, though ill-advised, to shadow a built-in command with a completely different command that doesn't necessarily take directories as arguments).

`bash`'s programmable completion facilities are pretty good, but for whatever reason, it does not actually include any such completions in the base installation. There is a [large set of completions available](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion), though, including one for [`cd`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L1672).